# how to write into a text file in php without delete all the data

Tags: php

how can I write into text file without erase all the existing data?
I tried this

```
$txt = 'srge';
$file = fopen('text.txt','w');
fwrite($file,$txt);
```

but it's not working, it's earse everything

Comment: Have you even looked at the docs - specifically the "mode" flag?

Comment: @John3136 yes, I did and you can be nicer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** This will only work when you have appropriate permission for `test.txt` else it will say

> **permission denied** (un-appropriate will lead to this)

Here we are using:

**1.** `a` which is for append this will append text at the end of file.

**2.** **instead of** `w`, flag `w` is for write, which will write on file without caring about you existing data in that file.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$txt = 'srge';
$file = fopen('text.txt','a');
fwrite($file,$txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

according to php documentation:

**while you are using :**

**'w'**     Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the beginning of the file** and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

**try instead:**

**'a'**     Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the end of the file.** If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
$txt = 'srge';
$file = fopen('text.txt','a');
fwrite($file,$txt);
```

### Writing or Appending to a File

The processes for writing to or appending to a file are the same. The difference lies in the fopen() call. When you write to a file, you should use the mode argument "w" when you call fopen():

```
$fp = fopen( "test.txt", "w" );
```

All subsequent writing will occur from the start of the file. If the file doesn't already exist, it will be created. If the file already exists, any prior content will be destroyed and replaced by the data you write.

When you append to a file, you should use mode "a" in your fopen() call:

```
$fp = fopen( "test.txt", "a" );
```

For more details please refer this : [**File operation example**](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29664&seqNum=7)

[**Php Filesystem Functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)

Comment: Could you explain (for future users) why you use mode `a` instead of `w`? This is the correct answer (only without explanation).

Comment: Please refer this till i am updating my answer : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29664&seqNum=7

Comment: @U.azar "a" (Write only. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)

Comment: @DavinderKumar yes I see now

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
 $content = 'any text';
 $file = fopen('file.txt','a');
 fwrite($file,$content);
```

Have you noticed i used mode a

"a" (Write only. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)